# Conditional Execution of ribbon button actions in CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have a custom ribbon button. I am using Ribbon Workbench to customize the button. I have created a command and assigned 3 actions to it.

The actions assigned are in the below sequence.

1. A javascript action - It checks for mandatory values in the CRM form and if there are any missing fields, this will return 'false'. the code is similar to the below

   event.returnValue=false;
   return false;
2. Url Action - assigned to a HTML web resource, and this will be opened as a modal dialog.
3. A javascript action - which is responsible for refreshing the page.

All these are working in the way they are coded. But what is that I am expecting is, if the first Javascript function returns 'false', it should not fire/invoke the remaining actions.

I checked all the available properties of Ribbon Workbench in the Action creation window. None seems to be relevant.

Can somebody help me.

Comment: Finally, I have decided to change the approch to open a pop-up. Basically, the reason why I have used the above approach is, I dont want to use window.showModalDialog explicitly. I assumed that this is not supported, but on a deeper analysis the MSDN document says that we should not use it to open CRM forms, so I safely assumed that using this to open custom HTML resource is supported. So I have merged everything into one JS file and handle all the cases within it.

Answer (score 0):

The actions will be called irrespective of the return value so you'll need to either add them all into the same action - or create a semaphore value on the window object that is checked by each action before firing. Of course this would rely on you changing the url action to be custom javascript action.